# Navigate to ViewModel From Current View Instead of RootView

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is there a way to navigate to a ViewModel from my current view instead the root view?

I have created a view model that is presented modally from the root view and wish to present a view model within that view.

For example, when calling `_navigationService.Navigate<MyViewModel>();` from my modal view, the root view navigates to MyViewModel instead of the current modal view. This leaves my modal screen with a blank page until you dismiss it and see that the navigation has taken place below.

Do I create a custom navigation, or is there a better way of going about this?

**EDIT**

Here is some code:

My View Model

```
 public class ViewModel1 : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public ViewModel1(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public IMvxCommand NavigateCommand => new MvxCommand(ChangeView);
    void ChangeView()
    {
        _navigationService.Navigate<ViewModel2>();
    }
}
```

My View

```
 [MvxModalPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true, ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom, Animated = false)]
public partial class MyView : MvxViewController
{
    ViewModel1 VM;

    public MyView() : base("MyView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, ViewModel1 >();
        set.Bind(NextButton).To(vm => vm.NavigateCommand);
        set.Apply();
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

I would like to have the navigation command present ViewModel2 within the presented modal.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Added some code :)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of customization, you may need a write a custom presenter and there you can fiddle around to achieve whatever you can achieve with native.

I am dropping some hint.

In AppDelegate, inside finish launching.

```
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {   

    Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            var presenter = new DelegatingPresenter(this, Window);
            var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
            setup.Initialize();

            var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
            startup.Start();
            ---
            ---
}
```

DelegatingPresenter looks like:

```
public class DelegatingPresenter : MvxIosViewPresenter {


        private UIWindow currentWindow;

        public DelegatingPresenter(AppDelegate appDelegate, UIWindow window)
            : base(appDelegate, window) {


            currentWindow = window;
            --
            ---

        }
        protected override void SetWindowRootViewController(UIViewController controller, MvvmCross.iOS.Views.Presenters.Attributes.MvxRootPresentationAttribute attribute = null)
        {
            base.SetWindowRootViewController(controller, attribute);
        }

        public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            var viewCreator = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxIosViewCreator>();

            var controller = (UIViewController)viewCreator.CreateView(request);
            Show((UIViewController)controller);
        }
        //public override void Show(IMvxIosView view) {

        //}

        public override void ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint) {

            ---
            ----
        }

        public override void Close(IMvxViewModel toClose) {

            ---
            ----
        }

        public void Show(UIViewController) {

         //if (viewController is IFlyoutNavigationControllerCapable) {
                //flyoutPresenter.Show(viewController, flyout);
            //}
            //else {
                //currentWindow.RootViewController = viewController;
                //navigationPresenter.Show(viewController, flyout);
            //}
    //Do your thing here.

        }

        public bool Close(FlyoutNavigationController flyout) {

---
----
        }
    }
```

Here, your point of interest are "show" method override thats gets called when load new ViewModel.
Here you have your rootviewController and new controller that you want to present, so I guess you can take it from here.